# SSRS 2010 Bar Chart Data Series

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Bar Chart that I am trying to limit Sales data to specific Months/Years. I want a SUM of Sales $ for 2012 and a SUM of Sales $ for 2013. The Month Names are formatted like January 2012, January 2013, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the 'Category Group Properties' and change it to group by year instead of just date.

1. Choose 'Category Groups' add a group like say 'dt' for our example which is a date field.
2. Click the down arrow now next to it and choose 'properties'.
3. On the 'General' pane select the 'Group on:' portion and click the 'fx' button for a function.
4. Put this in =Year(Fields!dt.Value)
5. Click OK

You now are overriding your default grouping and are now grouping by year instead of full date.  This process works for months and days as well.

IF your data field for date is not a legitimate date field you need to make sure it is a 'date' or 'datetime' data type first.